# Performance of standalone R script loading dependencies

Tags: python, r, amazon-web-services

I am working on a Python application that extracts data, transforms it, and then calls a script that visualizes the data.

The visualization component is handled by an R script. I'm aware you can do data visualization in Python, but that wouldn't work with my use case's requirements.

The R script has the following dependencies:

```
library('ggplot2')
library('dplyr')
library('tibble')
library('tidyr')
library('readr')
library('grid')
library('gridExtra')
library('magick')
library('ggpubr')
library('stringi')
```

The R script takes a CSV as input and outputs a graphic to a given directory.

It is called when the Python app is running:

```
subprocess.call(f"/usr/local/bin/Rscript --vanilla data.csv outdir", shell=True)
```

The app runs on my local machine but I am looking to run it on an EC2 instance, and the R script runs hundreds of times so the speed with which it generates the graphics is important.

I'm new to R and trying to understand whether my approach of using a standalone script that loads libraries is performant? What happens when I run the application on a machine in the cloud - do the packages have to be installed first on the host machine? Thank you.

Comment: This is a standard R question, and it actually has nothing to do with data science; it would be better off in Stack Overflow

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the site!

I faced similar issue sometime back I wrote a function to install the package if it is not available and if available then just load the package.

The following is the function.:

```
#required libraries
inst_pack <- function(x){
  for( i in x ){
    #  require returns TRUE invisibly if it was able to load package
    if( ! require( i , character.only = TRUE , quietly=TRUE ) ){
      #  If package was not able to be loaded then re-install
      suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(install.packages( i ,quietly=TRUE ,character.only = TRUE,message=FALSE)))#, dependencies = TRUE )))
      #  Load package after installing
      suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library( i , character.only = TRUE, quietly=TRUE)))
    }
    else{
      suppressWarnings(suppressMessages(library( i , character.only = TRUE, quietly=TRUE)))
    }
  }
}

inst_pack(c("DBI", "RMySQL", "RSQLite", "RODBC", "DMwR", "caret", "dplyr", "forecast", "forecastHybrid", "lubridate", 
            "sqldf" , "tsintermittent", "odbc","mailR", "data.table","readr","bsts","stringr","tidyr","zoo","reshape2",
            "RForcecom","chron"))
```

It doesn't even show any warning messages while loading the package.

I hope this answers your question.